# psycopg2: cursor.execute storing only table structure, no data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I am trying to store some tables I create in my code in an RDS instance using psycopg2. The script runs without issue and I can see the table being stored correctly in the DB. However, if I try to retrieve the query, I only see the columns, but no data:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import psycopg2 
    
    test=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[2,2]})
    
    #connect is a function to connect to the RDS instance
    connection= connect() 
    cursor=connection.cursor()

    query='CREATE TABLE test (A varchar NOT NULL,B varchar NOT NULL);'

    cursor.execute(query)
        
    connection.commit()

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

This script runs without issues and, printing out `file_check` from the following script:

```
   connection=connect()
   # check if file already exists in SQL
   sql = """
    SELECT "table_name","column_name", "data_type", "table_schema"
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE "table_schema" = 'public'
    ORDER BY table_name  
    """
   file_check=pd.read_sql(sql, con=connection)

   connection.close()
```

I get:

```
table_name column_name          data_type table_schema
0       test           a  character varying       public
1       test           b  character varying       public
```

which looks good.

Running the following however:

```
   read='select * from public.test'
   df=pd.read_sql(read,con=connection)
```

returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

Anybody have any idea why this is happening? I cannot seem to get around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this:
As it was pointed out by @AKX, I was only creating the table structure, but I was not filling in the table.

I now import `import psycopg2.extras` as well and, after this:

```
   query='CREATE TABLE test (A varchar NOT NULL,B varchar NOT NULL);'

   cursor.execute(query)
```

I add something like:

```
   update_query='INSERT INTO test(A, B) VALUES(%s,%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' 
   psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor, update_query, test.values)

   cursor.close()
   connection.close()
```

My table is now correctly filled after checking with `pd.read_sql`

Comment: If you just use `pd.to_sql()` with SQLAlchemy, you won't need to write the `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, your first script *has* a `test_tbl` dataframe, but it's never referred to after it's defined.

You'll need to

```
test_tbl.to_sql("test", connection)
```

or similar to actually write it.

A minimal example:

```
$ createdb so63284022
$ python
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> test = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1],'B':[2,2], 'C': ['yes', 'hello']})
>>> engine = sa.create_engine("postgres://localhost/so63284022")
>>> with engine.connect() as connection:
...     test.to_sql("test", connection)
...
>>>
$ psql so63284022
so63284022=# select * from test;
 index | A | B |   C
-------+---+---+-------
     0 | 1 | 2 | yes
     1 | 1 | 2 | hello
(2 rows)

so63284022=# \d+ test
                                   Table "public.test"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 index  | bigint |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 A      | bigint |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 B      | bigint |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 C      | text   |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "ix_test_index" btree (index)
Access method: heap

so63284022=#
```

Comment: sorry, typo in the question. Edited now. Thank you for noticing

Comment: You still aren't doing anything with `test` (née `test_tbl`).

Comment: Also, you don't need to create the table by hand with Pandas – it'll create one with a correct schema if you just do `to_sql()`.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was however able to find a way around sqlalchemy. Your example would work as well though

Comment: What... way around sqlalchemy? Either way, the original problem was that you never told Pandas to save anything to the database.

Comment: I didn't need to import sqlalchemy as in the example you provided. 
However, you correctly pointed out I was not filling the table, so I only had the structure in my RDS. I now added a query that fills the table. Seems to be working fine on my side

Comment: Oh, well, fine if it works without SQLAlchemy. [The Pandas docs just imply that the connection needs to be an SQLAlchemy connection or engine.](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql)